# clang BlocksRuntime embeds 'obsolete compiler' warning in executable when using __block

Tags: c++, c, clang, objective-c-blocks, clang++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Block.h>
int main()
{
  __block int x = 5;
  ^{printf("x is %i\n", x);}();
}
```

When I use clang to compile a c (or c++) program that uses both clang's blocks and the __block type specifier, no compiler warnings are produced, even using -Wall and -Wpedantic. The program also runs as expected. However, if I open the executable using a text editor, I find this block of text (extracted using 'strings' command):

```
Block_release called upon a stack Block: %p, ignored
_Block_byref_release: Block byref data structure at %p underflowed
Block compiled by obsolete compiler, please recompile source for this Block
descriptor->dispose helper: %p
byref data block %p contents:
^%p (new layout) =
isa?: %p
refcount: %u
invoke: %p
descriptor: %p
descriptor->reserved: %lu
descriptor->size: %lu
descriptor->copy helper: %p
  forwarding: %p
  flags: 0x%x
  size: %d
  copy helper: %p
  dispose helper: %p
NULL passed to _isa: stack Blockisa: malloc heapisa: GC heap Bloisa: global Blocisa: finalizing
```

The problem is that I am using the latest version of clang - hardly an 'obsolete' compiler. I am on Linux (musl) and I installed the BlocksRuntime from https://github.com/mackyle/blocksruntime. I also found the piece of code that generates the warning here - https://github.com/mackyle/blocksruntime/blob/master/BlocksRuntime/runtime.c#L629

```
λ: clang --version
clang version 10.0.0 
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /bin
λ: uname -a
Linux thinkpad 5.7.9_1 #1 SMP Thu Jul 16 10:02:50 UTC 2020 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Is it safe to ignore this warning? If not, what can I do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just realized that the warning is probably meant to be a runtime error stored as a string in the executable, which means that there is no problem. Disassembling seems to support this idea - radare2 shows the string in the .rodata section:[image: Screenshot of radare2 showing 'obsolete compiler' string in .rodata section]

I really should have though of that earlier...